# Error reading log bash script

Tags: bash, api, logging, tail

I'm having a problem with a bash script i'm writing. I want to read a logfile and do something with the output. But the problem is that it logs everytime two lines instead of one. So everytime i get a copy of the ouput instead of one line.

```
#!/bin/bash
##############

logfile=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-ing-security.log
counter_a=0
counter_b=0

tail -fn0 /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-jira-   security.log | \
while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | grep "FAILED"
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        echo "API action FAILED" >> $logfile
        counter_a=$((counter_a+1))
        echo "Total of $counter_a API actions FAILED" >> $logfile
    else
        echo "API action SUCCESFULL" >> $logfile
        counter_b=$((counter_b+1))
        echo "Total of $counter_b API actions SUCCESFULL" >> $logfile
    fi
 done
```

This is the output i am using in the script:

```
2016-07-05 20:11:28,335 http-bio-8080-exec-2917 anonymous 1211x943864x1 - 10.000.000.113,10.000.105.000 /rest/api/2/search HttpSession created [10n1nec]
2016-07-05 20:11:28,381 http-bio-8080-exec-2917 AABBCC 1211x943864x1 - 10.000.000.000,10.000.105.000 /rest/api/2/search The user 'AABBCC' has PASSED authentication.
```

How can i delete everytime the second line in the script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the output of `grep` is going to your script's standard output as well. You could simply silence it:

```
if echo "$line" | grep -q FAILED; then
    echo "API action FAILED" >> $logfile
    counter_a=$((counter_a+1))
    echo "Total of $counter_a API actions FAILED" >> $logfile
else
    echo "API action SUCCESFULL" >> $logfile
    counter_b=$((counter_b+1))
    echo "Total of $counter_b API actions SUCCESFULL" >> $logfile
fi
```

However, a better approach is to avoid the (relatively) expensive call to `grep` on every line and use the shell itself to detect matches.

```
tail ... | {
  while read line ; do
    if [[ $line = *FAILED* ]]; then
    then
        echo "API action FAILED"
        counter_a=$((counter_a+1))
    else
        echo "API action SUCCESSFUL"
        counter_b=$((counter_b+1))
    fi
  done
  # You probably want to execute these just once, after the entire
  # file has been processed.
  echo "Total of $counter_b API actions SUCCESSFUL"
  echo "Total of $counter_a API actions FAILED"
} >> "$logfile"
```

Comment: Thank you. Only problem is that the script has to run continuous instead of one scan. So every time when somebody executes an api the script has to log it to a external file.

Comment: If you really need a running count logged after each line, you can keep that part from the first snippet I show, and just replace the `grep` pipeline with the `[[ ... ]]` command.

Comment: Sadly enough it keeps logging two lines instead of one.. I don't get it anymore because the first line it doesn't have any of the founded syntax in it....